# Cached image looks worst than original from Magento 1.9

Tags: image, caching

we are having some strange issues with product image quality being very inconsistent. How do we fix this? Our cached product images looks very dull compared to the original ones.

WE tried to view the image from the original location and it looked good. But when Magento converted to a cached image, it got very dull.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for an image becoming dull, or tonally inaccurate is that an embedded ICC colour profile has been dropped, added or otherwise not respected.

To check if your *"before"* and *"after"* images have ICC colour profiles, use `exiftool` - available on Windows and all good OSes:

```
exiftool IMAGE.XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to compression. Either from an image compression module or server compression from generating the cached image.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33416972)